# I have pygame installed on my computer (ASUS Windows 10) and I am constantly getting a weird error

Tags: python, pygame, command, command-prompt

```
C:\Users\Name\Desktop>snk.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\snk.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\pygame.py", line 4, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have a file called `"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\pygame.py"`. I know this is true because you posted a stack trace that says so. That file is masking the real `pygame` module. Delete or rename it.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your file from `pygame.py` to `any_thing_else.py`;

because when you import pygame by using `import pygame` it's importing the same file again and agian!

I think this will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is named pygame, rename it to something else.
It is better to have a module have a name you haven’t used before